# How to slice multiple long strings in txt file using Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Maybe very simple to do this, but lack of experience.
I am trying to slice very long `.txt` file by using pandas or something in Python.

Text format. (more than 1000 lines in row)

```
PGB(1)         Output  Desc="flt"  Group="Main"  Max=2  Min=-2  Units=""
PGB(2)         Output  Desc="Vs:1"  Group="Main"  Max=400  Min=-400  Units="kV"
PGB(3)         Output  Desc="Vs:2"  Group="Main"  Max=400  Min=-400  Units="kV"
PGB(4)         Output  Desc="Vs:3"  Group="Main"  Max=400  Min=-400  Units="kV"
PGB(5)         Output  Desc="Is:1"  Group="Main"  Max=3  Min=-3  Units="kA"
PGB(6)         Output  Desc="Is:2"  Group="Main"  Max=3  Min=-3  Units="kA"
PGB(7)         Output  Desc="Is:3"  Group="Main"  Max=3  Min=-3  Units="kA"
PGB(8)         Output  Desc="TripSignal"  Group="Main"  Max=2  Min=-2  Units=""
PGB(9)         Output  Desc="Xcircle"  Group="dist_relay1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
PGB(10)        Output  Desc="Xca"  Group="dist_relay1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
PGB(11)        Output  Desc="Xc"  Group="dist_relay1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
PGB(12)        Output  Desc="Rca"  Group="dist_relay1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
PGB(13)        Output  Desc="Rc"  Group="dist_relay1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
PGB(14)        Output  Desc="Rcircle"  Group="dist_relay1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
PGB(15)        Output  Desc="Xbc"  Group="dist_relay1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
PGB(16)        Output  Desc="Xb"  Group="dist_relay1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
PGB(17)        Output  Desc="Rbc"  Group="dist_relay1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
PGB(18)        Output  Desc="Rb"  Group="dist_relay1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
PGB(19)        Output  Desc="Xab"  Group="dist_relay1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
PGB(20)        Output  Desc="Xa"  Group="dist_relay1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
PGB(21)        Output  Desc="Rab"  Group="dist_relay1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
PGB(22)        Output  Desc="Ra"  Group="dist_relay1"  Max=600.0  Min=-600.0  Units=""
```

I used this kind of code below :

```
file_path=os.path.join(cwd, 'TEST.inf')

df_index=pd.read_fwf(file_path,sep='\t',names=['PGB','Outputs','SignalName'])
```

However, it seems `sep='\t'` is not able to seperate texts from Desc.
Results are 1000 rows and 3 colums, meaning that for example

```
Desc="Block_NC:5"  Group="V_S2P1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
```

part is regarded as one column, not 5 column.

What i have expected was having 5 columns by using `\t` separator, but it is not.
Can anyone give some advice how to separate data in the text file ? I can manually slice this column of course, but i wonder if there are easier ways ?.
or is there any command in pandas that i can extract some text inside of "" ? what i need at the end is only text in "" of Desc.

Comment: You need 3 columns right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace = True, header=None)`

it works on the copy and pasted example you gave, I hope it should work on your file as well:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
"""

PGB(495)       Output  Desc="Block_NC:2"  Group="V_S2P1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""

PGB(496)       Output  Desc="Block_NC:3"  Group="V_S2P1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""

PGB(497)       Output  Desc="Block_NC:4"  Group="V_S2P1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""

PGB(498)       Output  Desc="Block_NC:5"  Group="V_S2P1"  Max=2.0  Min=-2.0  Units=""
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace = True, header=None)
df
```

produces

```
    0           1       2                   3                   4       5            6
0   PGB(495)    Output  Desc="Block_NC:2"   Group="V_S2P1"  Max=2.0 Min=-2.0    Units=""
1   PGB(496)    Output  Desc="Block_NC:3"   Group="V_S2P1"  Max=2.0 Min=-2.0    Units=""
2   PGB(497)    Output  Desc="Block_NC:4"   Group="V_S2P1"  Max=2.0 Min=-2.0    Units=""
3   PGB(498)    Output  Desc="Block_NC:5"   Group="V_S2P1"  Max=2.0 Min=-2.0    Units=""
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments !. I tried your code, but it seems there are some errors as below :  "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 34, saw 9" Can you guess what the problem is ? if i just use sep='\t', then the code works, but results are just one single column data, not multiple column.

Comment: @James the error sounds like line 34 of the input has some extra whitespace somewhere so the parser thinks it has 9 elements not 7. The command I suggested would split on any whitespace, that worked for the snipped you posted but if the file has varying number of whitespaces it won't. you can either ensure that all lines in the file are "the same" or post troublesome lines here and \i will take a look if things could be modified to work

Comment: thanks for your comments, I think my original post already includes correct information, but to be sure i have updated it. Could you check if you are available ? I directly copy and paste txt in .inf file in my original questions. I would like to attach .inf file on my questions, but it seems those functions are not supported in stackoverflow. Thanks.

Comment: @James what you pasted in your latest edit still works with my code, but it only has 21 lines whereas the error seems to be in line 34 of your txt file?

Comment: I just copied part of .inf file as it is more than 1000 lines. BTW, I just copied what i put in the update to .inf file and run the script as you commented. It works !, but if i run original .inf file, it doesnt work. It is strange...

Comment: @James as I said it seems you have extra space on some of the lines, the error you mentioned some time before indicated it was around line 34

Comment: I think i found some differences based on your comments, Thanks.!